# How to limit zoomScale up to months in dc.js chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I created a chart having brush with zoom feature. My X-axis of chart data values is in dates.

I am trying to limit the maximum zoom to months.

I tried

```
chart.zoomScale([1, 3])
```

but it didn't work.
[This is the image of chart with having zoom, subChart with brush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59vtL.png)

How can I set the limit at months in zoom & brush?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you currently have to determine zooming limits based on a ratio to the current domain of the chart.

[Here is the documentation for `d3.zoom.scaleExtent()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_scaleExtent), where this parameter goes:

> sets the scale extent to the specified array of numbers `[k0, k1]` where `k0` is the minimum allowed scale factor and `k1` is the maximum allowed scale factor

So

```
chart.zoomScale([1, 3])
```

means you can only zoom out to 1:1, and only zoom in to 3:1. If you are displaying 3 months of data, this should be the limits you want. But otherwise, you would want to set the second value to the number of months you are displaying.

Does this make sense? Does it work?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will try setting values d3.zoom.scaleExtent().One another scenario I have to handle that after brush selection need to change zoom limit so in any situation data won't shown more than months.

Comment: You are already setting `scaleExtent`: that's what `zoomScale` does. By "brush with zoom feature" do you mean the range/focus chart feature as shown in the chart "Monthly Index Abs Move and Volume" on the [dc.js home page](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)?

Comment: yes Gordon, I am using range/focus chart feature, added chart image link in the question.

Comment: Hi **Gordon**, can you help me on this?